# How to do On="1" and Off="2" within one button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using two buttons for "on" and "off". When I press "On" button, it passes a string value "1", and pressing the "Off" button passes the string value "2".

How can I do this within one button? By default button should be off, when I press it should on and when i press again it should off.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SerialPort ardo;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ardo = new SerialPort();
        ardo.PortName = "COM5";
        ardo.BaudRate = 9600;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stop = "1";
        ardo.Open();
        ardo.Write(stop);
        ardo.Close();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string On = "2";
        ardo.Open();
        ardo.Write(On);
        ardo.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Either store current state in session or get current state from the serial port if possible and toggle it

Comment: Can you give any example that how can i store current state in session ?

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //consider initially its stopped
       if(Session[“currentState”] == null)
           Session[“currentState”] = “1”;

       if(Session[“currentState”].ToString() == “1”)
         {

            Session[“currentState”]= “2”;
         }
         else
         {

            Session[“currentState”]= “1”; 
         }
        ardo.Open();
        ardo.Write(Session[“currentState”].ToString());
        ardo.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it set to hidden text box.

then you can check if statement it is pressed or not

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // hf means hidden textbox
      if(hf.text==1){
    // your on code
       hf.text=0;
        }
       if(hf.text==0){
    //your off code
      hf.text=1;
        }

 }
```

Comment: Please help me on this. How can i set hidden box ?

Comment: yes.normlly add text box.lets say it is textbox1.then add this to load event , 

textbox1.Visible = false;

Answer (score 0):

Declare a string variable

```
private string isOn = "2";
```

and then on the button click event you can handle it like

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(isOn.Equals("2"))
        isOn = "1";
    else
        isOn = "2";

}
```